# How to async sending API request process in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm doing a project in which, on loading(render) a page through views, an API request is sent.

I want to async the API request process, i.e in intervals of 10sec, API requests should be sent.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) along with [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/).

Very good tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFn4_nA_yk8).